# Accessing length of Array in Javascript JSON for Morris chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, morris.js

So I am building Morris charts and have written an API for accessing dynamic data from a SQLAlchemy database. The data is sent to the page is a JSON format and I am able to access all the elements of the array. The issue is when I try to access the 'length' value of an array. It returns nothing as far as I can see. The following is what I am trying to send to my morris chart and it doesnt populate any data where as when I write 'id' rather than 'sessions.length' the id value is populated in to the Morris chart:

```
var chart = Morris.Bar({
    element: 'myfirstchart',
    data: [0,0],
    xkey: ['cert_status'],
    ykeys: ['sessions.length'],
    labels: ['sessions']
});
```

The data is being returned in this format:

```
[
  {
    "cert_status": "Testing", 
    "id": 1, 
    "sessions": [
      1, 
      2
    ]
  }, 
  {
    "cert_status": "Certified", 
    "id": 2, 
    "sessions": []
  }, 
  {
    "cert_status": "Stopped", 
    "id": 3, 
    "sessions": []
  }, 
  {
    "cert_status": "Initial Setup", 
    "id": 4, 
    "sessions": []
  }
]
```

Comment: Whi have you put `sessions.length` in quotes?

Comment: @Pointy without the quotes I get an 'Uncaught ReferenceError: sessions is not defined'. I am assuming that to access the 'data' that is being passed in from another Javascript function for accessing the API it has to be in quotes.

Comment: That would not be a correct assumption. If it's undefined, then that means that the JSON has not been turned into a JavaScript array properly or that it's not assigned to a variable called "sessions".